# Two seemingly equal ways of changing column names for R data.frame - only the other one works

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I need to add suffix to some of the variable names. In my case that's all numerical variables after spreading a variable to wide format. Could someone explain me why the first option does not work but the second does:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = "id", var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = 3)
```

1.

```
colnames(df[,2:ncol(df)]) <- paste0(names(df[,2:ncol(df)]), "_X")
```

2.

```
colnames(df) <- c("ID", paste0(names(df[,2:ncol(df)]), "_X"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are subsetting your `df`, in essence creating a second data.frame, and renaming it. This does not reflect on your original data.frame.

```
colnames(df[,2:ncol(df)]) <- paste0(names(df[, 2:ncol(df)]), "_X")
```

would be equal to

```
df2 <- df[,2:ncol(df)]
colnames(df2) <- paste0(names(df[, 2:ncol(df)]), "_X")

> df
  ID var1 var2 var3
1 id    1    2    3
> df2
  var1_X var2_X var3_X
1      1      2      3
```

The correct way would be

```
colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)] <- paste0(names(df[, 2:ncol(df)]), "_X")
```

or using `sprintf`

```
colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)] <- sprintf("%s_X", names(df)[2:ncol(df)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your fist command contains syntax errors. We can fix it to:

```
colnames(df[,2:ncol(df)]) <- paste0(names(df[,2:ncol(df)]), "_X")
```

That doesn't return an error, but still doesn't work. You assign column names to a subset of a data.frame, but that subset is never stored and the command doesn't change the names of the full data.frame.

You need to assign to a subset of the names:

```
colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)] <- paste0(names(df)[2:ncol(df)], "_X")
```